# how to share customized video on facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, video, video-streaming, customization

I want to share my customized video on facebook. I have customized a video player using [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/)

Now I want a button on my webpage and when I click on that it should share the same video on facebook. (e.g I have changed the color of play button, after 10 seconds it is showing alert message, and so many other customization)

I am looking for the functionalities like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eajZVCkiPcE

Can you guys let me know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and what kind of difficulties you have found?

Comment: @Micho I did not try any code since I am not able to find out any code over google.

Comment: Not possible. You can not embed custom JavaScript into the Facebook feed.

Comment: @CBroe brother can you please look at this video functionality https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eajZVCkiPcE If it is not possible then how are these guys doing.

Comment: I am not going to watch a whole video to then guess what you might be talking about. Anyway, the are probably just using a custom flash player.

Comment: @CBroe you don't need to see whole video. In first minute of video you will get to know what do I mean? Please have a look if you can, might be that can help me. Thanks

Comment: Whatever functionality you see there has to be flash, because that is the only kind of “interactive” content you can currently embed (besides flash, mp4 videso can be embedded as well – but with those you won’t get any kind of interactivity of that sort.) Anything else that you might have seen on Facebook, f.e. a custom HTML5 audio player like SoundCloud uses, only works because those companies have a special partnership with Facebook that allows them to embed that kind of content. But because of the security implications this has, they don’t allow other developers to do this right now.

Comment: Sorry @CBroe I didn't get you. It's fine that it should be flash but when I am creating a video player with js which is also in flash I think. You can look at here http://104.239.230.252/beta/index.php/watch?v=20  this one is mine which I want to share which is not happening while http://vsrv.us/sv4/?id=192  this one is a reference which is working

Comment: You can _only_ embed a `.swf` flash file directly. Rendering the player for that `.swf` file is what Facebook does.

Comment: And can you tell me @CBroe what's my format  http://104.239.230.252/beta/index.php/watch?v=20  ? and how can I get this to share